# Flask error setting session attribute: BadPayload

Tags: python, session, flask

I'm having trouble setting a flask session attribute. I cannot set session['var_name'] to anythign without getting a `BadPayload: Could not load the payload because an exception occurred on unserializing the data` error. The below code throws an error. but if I comment out `session['a'] = 1` and it runs fine. Seem's like its an itsdangerous error. Should I be setting me secret_key to something better than gobblygook? Is that related?

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, session

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'sdfnbsifhosdfsdsfsddfsdfiewl'

@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def index():
    session['a'] = 1
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=7777, debug=True)
```

Comment: No errors found here reproducing your code. Maybe you are calling the url with a bad payload on request.

Comment: This error is commonly associated to [`itsdangerous`](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/itsdangerous/blob/master/itsdangerous.py#L541) lib when trying to use serializer.

Comment: Thanks, what does that mean exactly? Where else would you suggest looking for the root of the issue? @MauroBaraldi

Comment: I don't know what the issue is but upgrading simplejsonfrom 3.8.0 to 3.8.2 solved this issue

Comment: Perhaps you was caught in [this bug](https://github.com/simplejson/simplejson/issues/128) that was fixed in 3.8.1